# Capture Name from Driver's license // PCI Card Reader

Tags: database, textbox, pci-compliance

I have an iMag PCI card reader and an SDK that goes along with it. Having said that, I'm a pretty novice iOS developer, so the SDK isnt completely clear to me.

My project goal is this; PCI card reader is connected to an iPad - The app has multiple text fields for data entry, including a Name field. To speed the process of Login and Logout, along with the feeling of increased security (I work at a data center), I was hoping to make the card reader swipe a government issued ID (state license), and store -just the name- in a text field. This assures that that the information in our database is accurate, and "you are who you say you are". An automated timestamp is also a plus.

Following that, the user then manually enters other text fields, such as "Reason for Visit". Time time of login is stored upon submission into a database. To Logout, the user simply selects a different View inside the app, swipes their ID, and can walk out.

Caveats- persons with the exact same name on premise concurrently could cause a problem, but i really dont see that happening :-)

-- Has anyone completed a project similar to this in the past? Altogether, the App should have about 4 views, and simple pictures/text/ and a handful of text entry forms.

Something I'm trying to figure out is wether my method of storing the data entered in the text fields, then offloading that to a database, and then also logging out will have a direct impact on how my app pulls the Name of the user from a license. Or are those completely independent from a development perspective, and can be handled independently?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. I did some forum searching and the PCI card readers seem to be a pretty fragmented market, so I don't know if many people will be familiar with the iMag, or the SDK i have received along with it.

Thanks,

Charlie

Comment: Just general advice: This isn't really a question. This site is geared to specific questions which can, at least in theory, be unambiguously answered. I suspect you'll soon have people voting to close this post. (I'm not -- I say if people think your question is too vague to reply, then don't reply. But there are plenty on here who will.)

Answer (score 0):

Whether you get data by the user keying it in or by picking it up from a card swipe should make no difference to how you ultimately store it on a database. We have a similar process here: we use barcode scanners, so the user can scan the product id with the barcode, or if an item has no barcode label or it's damaged and won't scan or whatever, they can key it in. Either way we populate a field on the form with the product id, and from there on the program doesn't know or care where it came from.

"persons with the exact same name on premise concurrently could cause a problem, but i really dont see that happening" I'd be very cautious about just hoping this will never happen. What happens if/when it does? I've seen plenty of systems where someone said, "Oh, the probability of that ever happening is a million to one, we just won't worry about it." Then the first day the system is deployed it happens twice. Systems that "ought to usually work" are very scary. I don't know how many customers you might have at one time. Do you plan to save data between visits? Is there only a problem if two customers with the same name are in the store at the same time, or is there a problem if two people who were EVER customers have the same name? But even if they both have to be in the store at the same time to cause trouble, it could happen. Using a drivers license to validate the customer's name might be a good idea, but don't use that as the identifier of the customer: give them some unique id.

Other stray thoughts:

"To Logout, the user simply selects a different View inside the app, swipes their ID, and can walk out." Why does the user need to swipe again to log out? Is there a potential that someone else could log the person out without their consent? But for that to happen, the user would have to walk away from the terminal while logged in. If someone else can walk up and start using the system under that person's id, the possibility that they will log them out should be the least of your security concerns. And what if someone leaves the store (or whatever this is) without swiping again? Do they stay logged in forever? I would think that if someone walks away without logging out, you WANT to make it easy for someone to just click a button and log them out.

I don't know your app. Could you have users who don't have a drivers license, or who have a license from a different state? I don't know if there's any sort of standard about data stored on the mag strip on drivers licenses, or if all states have mag strips.

Comment: "I don't know your app. Could you have users who don't have a drivers license, or who have a license from a different state? I don't know if there's any sort of standard about data stored on the mag strip on drivers licenses, or if all states have mag strips." -- I figured that because computer systems at say, a local bar, all display the information correctly, there must be some sor of standard to the information on the mag strip Following that, users are logged into our system upon entering the building, and then logout when they leave. In the interim they are escorted around.

Comment: Also for the names- Dont you feel as though, if using a licence, it really is a low probability that they would have the same first/ lastname, and middle initial? I would hope people wont shut it down, as they really isnt a clear how-to discussion regarding this topic on the internet, at least that I could find in a hour of searching.  Also, for users without a license, we generally would warn them that they must bring it for their next visit, but could manually enter information on this visit, similar to how you manually enter information if your barcodes are damaged

Comment: RE log in when enter and log out when leave: So I think you're saying that it's not really logging in to the computer system, it's registering when they enter and leave the building, as part of some security scheme maybe? Okay, that would make my objection moot I think.

Comment: RE duplicate names: Can you say that you are 100% certain that there will never ever ever be two people in your building both named, say, "Mary N Smith" or "Muhammed Ali"? I wouldn't want to build a system that relies on simply hoping that problem situations don't come up.

Comment: RE drivers license standard: I have no idea if there's a standard of not. You might want to investigate that before you run too far. If there's a manual workaround and most of your customers/clients/whatever are local, that may not be a big deal. If you routinely have people flying in from all over the country, then I'd want to do some research.

Comment: Jay, the customers are 95% local ( or at least from Pennsylvania, where we are based). And regarding the names, they would have to be in the building at the same time (we dont have more than 5 or so a day), and work for the same company. I understand your point, but I'm just trying to figure out a good course of action to get something functional running